# Override result_list templatetag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have custom `change_list.html` and `change_list_results.html` and would like to pass data from model admin.
I can get the data on `change_list.html` but not in `change_list_results.html`.
After researching on the internet the problem is in `change_list_results.html`, it's using templatetag `result_list`, by default `take_context` is set to `False`.
Below is the code of my model admin:

```py
class HistoryAdmin(UpdateUserAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('created_date', DateRangeFilter),
    )
    list_per_page = sys.maxsize
    actions = None
    list_display_links = None
    list_display = ('created_date', 'patient', 'price', 'payment')
    readonly_fields = ('created_date', 'updated_date')

    def get_rangefilter_created_date_default(self, request):
        return (datetime.date.today, datetime.date.today)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('created_date__range__gte'), "%d-%m-%Y").date()
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('created_date__range__lte'), "%d-%m-%Y").date()
        default_start_date = History.objects.first().created_date.date
        default_end_date = History.objects.latest('created_date').created_date.date
        results = History.objects.filter(created_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
        total_payment = str(results.aggregate(Sum('payment'))['payment__sum'])
        total_price = str(results.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum'])
        extra_context = {'title': CONSTANTS.MODEL_SINGLE_HISTORY, 'total_payment': total_payment, 'total_price': total_price}
        print(f'{results.values}  {total_payment} {total_price}')
        return super(HistoryAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

I can access `total_payment` and `total_price` in `change_list.html` like this:

```py
{{ total_payment }}
{{ total_price }}
```

Can anyone please help on how to access it in `change_list_results.html`?
Thanks in advance.